# How to pass xml while requesting Rest web service

Tags: java, android

I want to pass xml to rest web service with request. I am unable to get how I can do this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you need a code sample:

```
String response = null;

    httppost = new HttpPost(URL_STRING);
    httppost.setParams(httpParams);

    String s = your_XML_Data_As_String_Or_JSON_Or_Whatever;

    try {

        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(s);
        httppost.setEntity(entity);
        httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "SomeMIMEType");

        response = httpclient.execute(httppost, handler);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not send a file through a request, you just convert that file to something you can send over. Here is an example: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xml2jsonphp/